# What is optimal way to supply voltage for MOSFET gate driver circuit

Tags: gate-driving

Most FET Vgs are about 7 to 15V, if we use supply voltage in this range we can feed supply voltage to gate driver ICs or circuit.
But, what if our circuit work on higher supply voltage range,says 9 to 25V.
What is optimal way to regulate voltage for gate driver that work for whole supply voltage range?

As far as I known, for this application, I don’t need much current and don’t need precise voltage.

1. Linear regulator can work but may not work at low voltage supply due to drop out voltage
2. LDO Linear regulator is doing  better job at low voltage.
3. Buck converter seem to be overkill for such a low power and suffered from ripple and noise.
4. Zener diode + Resistor at gate. Seem not efficient at high supply voltage.
5. Zener diode + BJT as regulator, I found this method in Chinese tl494 boost converter. Seem to work with cost efficiency.

Comment: There is no optimal way, until you know what the rest of the system is, and what your requirements for it are. Once you have a definite system, how to do a small power supplies like this usually become obvious.

Comment: I'd stick a regulator or LDO in there plus decoupling caps and call it done. That's the simplest solution and you haven't given any requirements that contraindicate it.